# How to Install an NSIS Executable Silently For All Users

Tags: command-line, windows-installer, installation, nsis, silent-installer

I have an NSIS installer executable which I would like to install silently for all users. I know I can pass the `/S` argument to do a silent install. The problem is that the default option for the installer is to install only for the current user. How can I change this option from the command line:

```
installer.exe /S
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for this particular installer you can pass:

```
/ALLUSERS=1
```

`ALLUSERS` is a standard MSI property. I did not find any documentation for this property in NSIS, so it looks like the developers of this particular installer added this.

Answer (score 6):

NSIS itself just supports `/S`, `/NCRC` and `/D=c:\override\default\installdir\`, everything else is up the author.

If the custom page from your screenshot was created with [MultiUser.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/MultiUser/Readme.html) and the author defined `MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_COMMANDLINE` then you could use `installer.exe /AllUsers /S`, otherwise you have to ask the author of the installer if they are checking for a specific command line switch.

If it turns out there is no way to do it then you would have to look into UI automation...